# Ember Simple Auth (Devise) after update, authenticate break

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, devise, coffeescript, ember-simple-auth

I did an update from 0.6.4 to 0.7.2 with Ember Simple Auth (not Ember CLI version) for devise, now my authentification doesn't work at all :(, do you have an idea ? thank you very much for your help :)

PS : apparently, ApplicationController (application_controller.rb) don't continue after authenticate_with_http_token do |token, options| and authenticate_with_http_token is empty (tested with puts)

**login_controller.js**

```
App.LoginController = Ember.Controller.extend(SimpleAuth.LoginControllerMixin, {
  authenticator: 'simple-auth-authenticator:devise'
  //authenticator: 'authenticator:custom'
});
```

**application.js.coffee**

```
Ember.Application.initializer
  name: "authentication"
  after: "simple-auth"
  initialize: (container, application) ->
    applicationRoute = container.lookup("route:application")
    session = container.lookup("simple-auth-session:main")
    # handle the session events
    session.on "sessionAuthenticationSucceeded", ->

      applicationRoute.transitionTo "Myspace"
      return

    return

window.ENV = window.ENV || {}
window.ENV["simple-auth"] = { store: 'simple-auth-session-store:local-storage', authorizer: "simple-auth-authorizer:devise" };
window.ENV['simple-auth-devise'] = {
    crossOriginWhitelist: ['*'], 
    serverTokenEndpoint: 'users/sign_in',
  };
```

**login.hbs**

```
<br />
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <form {{action 'authenticate' on='submit'}}>
          <label for="identification">Login</label>
          {{input id='identification' placeholder='Enter Login' value=identification}}
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          {{input id='password' placeholder='Enter Password' type='password' value=password}}
          <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**login_route.js.coffee**

```
App.LoginRoute = Ember.Route.extend(

  #model: (params) ->
    #return @store.find('user', @get('session.user_id'))

  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    #controller.set "content", model
    controller.set "errorMessage", null
    return

  actions:
    sessionAuthenticationFailed: (responseBody) ->
      message = responseBody.error
      @controller.set "errorMessage", message
      console.log "errorMessage : " + message
      return )
```

**myspace_route.js.coffee**

```
App.MyspaceRoute = Ember.Route.extend(SimpleAuth.AuthenticatedRouteMixin,  ....)
```

**session_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { super }
      format.json do
        self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
        sign_in(resource_name, resource)
        data = {
          user_token: self.resource.authentication_token,
          user_email: self.resource.email
        }
        render json: data, status: 201
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session,
      if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format =~ %r{application/json} }

  before_filter :skip_trackable, :authenticate_user_from_token!

  private

    def skip_trackable
      request.env['warden'].request.env['devise.skip_trackable'] = '1'
    end

    def authenticate_user_from_token!
      puts "authentification"
      puts authenticate_with_http_token
      authenticate_with_http_token do |token, options|
        user_email = options[:user_email].presence
        user       = user_email && User.find_by_email(user_email)
        puts "user.authentication_token"
        puts user.authentication_token
        puts token
        puts "token"
        if user && Devise.secure_compare(user.authentication_token, token)
          sign_in user, store: false
        end
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: You can implement the `sessionAuthenticationSucceeded` in the application route (when you use the `ApplicationRouteMixin`) instead of listing to the session event in the initializer - makes it much simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of marcoow, just modified https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/tree/master/packages/ember-simple-auth-devise#server-side-setup SessionsController like this :

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { super }
      format.json do
        self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
        sign_in(resource_name, resource)
        @data = {
          user_token: self.resource.authentication_token,
          user_email: self.resource.email
        }
        render json: @data.to_json, status: 201
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now it's working

**Edit :**  to_json explanation : http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json

Answer (score 0):

You're setting up the `window.ENV` object in the initializer that runs after the `'simple-auth'` initializer so Ember Simple Auth cannot actually see the values that you set when its initializer runs. Make sure the values are set **before** the `'simple-auth'` initializer runs.

Also you should switch to Ember CLI of course ;)

Comment: what requests are made? what are the responses if requests are made? do you see any errors?

Comment: No javascript error, he my next post i give you more details, it's a simple request of login with the form

Answer (score 0):

After a run of debugger, it goes to :

**ember-simple-auth.js**

```
authenticate: function() {
    var args          = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var authenticator = args.shift();
    Ember.assert('Session#authenticate requires the authenticator factory to be specified, was ' + authenticator, !Ember.isEmpty(authenticator));
    var _this            = this;
    var theAuthenticator = this.container.lookup(authenticator);
    Ember.assert('No authenticator for factory "' + authenticator + '" could be found', !Ember.isNone(theAuthenticator));
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      theAuthenticator.authenticate.apply(theAuthenticator, args).then(function(content) {
        _this.setup(authenticator, content, true);
        resolve(); // <- it goes to here
      }, function(error) {
        _this.clear();
        _this.trigger('sessionAuthenticationFailed', error);
        reject(error);
      });
    });
  },
```

The json response with token seems to be ok, and authenticator config seems to be ok also ...

Also i have a "Rejected" in this promise

**ember-simple-auth.js**

```
 restore: function() {
        var _this = this;
        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          var restoredContent = _this.store.restore();
          var authenticator   = restoredContent.authenticator;
          if (!!authenticator) {
            delete restoredContent.authenticator;
            _this.container.lookup(authenticator).restore(restoredContent).then(function(content) {
              _this.setup(authenticator, content);
              resolve();
            }, function() {
              _this.store.clear();
              reject();
            });
          } else {
            _this.store.clear();
            reject();
          }
        });
      },
```

Trace of the Rejected promise :

```
VM7522:164 Ember Inspector (Promise Trace): 
    at new Promise (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:10174:9)
    at __exports__.default.Ember.ObjectProxy.extend.restore (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-simple-auth.js?body=1:1116:16)
    at __exports__.default (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-simple-auth.js?body=1:1337:15)
    at __exports__.default.initialize (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-simple-auth.js?body=1:447:9)
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:43164:11
    at visit (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:43556:7)
    at DAG.topsort (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:43610:11)
    at Namespace.extend.runInitializers (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:43161:15)
    at Namespace.extend._initialize (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:43046:14)
```

**Edit 1:**  and also this one :

**ember-simple-auth-devise.js**

```
  restore: function(properties) {
    var _this            = this;
    var propertiesObject = Ember.Object.create(properties);
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      if (!Ember.isEmpty(propertiesObject.get(_this.tokenAttributeName)) && !Ember.isEmpty(propertiesObject.get(_this.identificationAttributeName))) {
        resolve(properties);
      } else {
        reject();
      }
    });
  },
```

with trace :

```
 Ember Inspector (Promise Trace): 
    at new Promise (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:10174:9)
    at __exports__.default.Base.extend.restore (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-simple-auth-devise.js?body=1:156:16)
    at apply (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:7993:27)
    at superWrapper [as restore] (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:7571:15)
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-simple-auth.js?body=1:1121:51
    at invokeResolver (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:10192:9)
    at new Promise (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:10178:9)
    at __exports__.default.Ember.ObjectProxy.extend.restore (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-simple-auth.js?body=1:1116:16)
    at __exports__.default (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-simple-auth.js?body=1:1337:15)
```

Comment: if the promise returned by `restore` rejects that means something is  missing in the session data or maybe a property has the wrong name or so...

Comment: I'll Check that ! Thank you. Maybe my rails user serializer ?

Comment: In fact, ember_simple_auth:session when I get('session') exist, but _lastData is empty ... No user_token and no user_email can be found in get('session.user_token') or get('session').get('store').get('user_token') ...
I checked all my params, i really don't understand why it doesn't work. thank for you help @marcoow
PS : Also, thank you for your work on this project, it is very helpful, essential item with ember

Comment: Check what `content` is at `_this.setup(authenticator, content, true);` in the session's `authenticate` method.

Comment: `sessions: Array[3]
0: Array[2]
0: "user_id"
1: 2
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
1: Array[2]
0: "user_token"
1: "koGRTMTuG6DzmL-j94xr"
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
2: Array[2]
0: "user_email"
1: "thxxxx@gmail.com"`

Comment: sorry : 

`sessions { "user_id" => 2, "user_token => "koGRTMTuG6DzmL-j94xr", "user_email" => "thxxx@gmail.com" }`

Comment: Yeah, that's not what the devise authenticator expects - see here: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/tree/master/packages/ember-simple-auth-devise#server-side-setup

Comment: It's about `user_id` ? because, it was just added for the test. Unless, it's still bugging.

Comment: looks like you have a surrounding "sessions" key (`{ "sessions": { user_token: "… }  }`)? The devise authenticator expects `{ user_token: "… }`.